# Adapt app to the resizable iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, resize

I find my app looked very bad on the new simulator resizable iphone. Cause the app has used a lot xib. The layout was messed up. Is there any way to help to adapt app to the new resizable iphone (may be iphone 6)? 
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Are you using Auto-Layout?

Comment: follow some NSLayoutConstraints tutorials

Comment: Thanks a lot. The table view fit very well, But the cell can't. And for some custom views the size is some how fixed and the position is relative. To fix these need a lot of things to do. Does apple provide any way to help to do these. For android, It has many mechanism to adapt different size.

Comment: Bogdan Somlea and Droppy the auto-layout and the NSLayoutConstraints   are usefull. Thank you.